# Reg file - what does "dword" convert to?

Tags: c++, windows, types, registry

I have a reg file which I'm trying to read.
There's a type "**dword**" in some of the values...

```
"check"=dword:000001f4
"blah"=dword:000000c8
"test"=dword:00000000
"hello"=dword:00000000
```

What C++ type should I convert it to ? and how ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `dword` is a double word, where a word is the old (Intel 8086) 16-bit word.

So, it converts to the WinAPI-specific type `DWORD`, or the standard C (but not yet standard C++) type `uint32_t`. An `unsigned long` is guaranteed by C++03 to be large enough to hold 32-bits values as well, but may be wasteful on 64-bit platforms. An `unsigned int` will be large enough on MSVC++.

Conversion (if you have a hex string) can be done using `strtoul`.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the MSDN Library article for RegQueryValueEx and following the link for the lpType argument, you'll arrive at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724884%28VS.85%29.aspx).  A quick summary:

- REG_BINARY : variable length array of bytes
- REG_DWORD : a 32-bit number
- REG_QWORD : a 64-bit number
- REG_SZ : C string
- REG_EXPAND_SZ : C string with %environment% variable
- REG_MULTI_SZ : array of C strings

with the bizarro ones omitted.  There's only one good candidate: REG_DWORD.  It is very common.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google will tell you that a DWORD is two words, and a WORD is two bytes on Windows (a throwback from 16-bit Windows, not to be confused with a "word" in hardware specifications or other OS's, where it may be 32 bits or more).  So a DWORD is 32 bits, just as the width of the hex values you show suggests.

Anyway, if you include Windows header files, you can simply use the `DWORD` type defined there.

Comment: A word is 32 bits on a 32 bit architecture, so there's a little confusion here.

Comment: Not true in the context of Windows: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx - Windows has always defined WORD as 16 bits, since it started on 16-bit Windows.  I'll update my answer to clarify that I'm talking about Windows' WORD rather than the lower-case "word" which (you are correct) could be larger in non-Windows contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Use `uint32_t` from `<stdint.h>`.

Parsing can be done using `strtoul()` and then converting (don't assume that `unsigned long` and `uint32_t` are the same).